# SQL Variable Inserting INSIDE mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to make a price slider with PHP and SQL , but i have a problem when i have some problem in this code

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM price WHERE phone_price BETWEEN" .$from. "AND" .$to. );
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
print $row['phone_name'];
print $row['phone_price'];
print '';
}
```

I want to run the SQL query like `SELECT * FROM price WHERE phone_price BETWEEN 300 AND 500`

I am making a beta version therefore i am accepting the $from and $to values from `<input>` , i think i am making the error in inserting the variable in mysql_query .

THE ERROR -`Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\slide\slide.php on line 28`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a mistake in your query. Spaces needed after BETWEEN and AND. Otherwise php reads your query like `...BETWEEN123AND1234...`. And you should better use quotes to place vars:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `price` WHERE `phone_price` BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to."'");
```

Comment: Don't use quotes around number.

Comment: but why do you put things inside quotes 'price' ??

Comment: $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM price WHERE phone_price BETWEEN " .$from. " AND " .$to );
 
i just added spaces and everything worked

Comment: Well quotes around number are not necessary, but it make code more structured. But spaces between BETWEEN and AND are necessary.

Comment: can you tell how can i get the value of $from and $to , through a slider

Comment: you can use jquery like to send request to your script or make it though form and posting vasr, or by url like somesite.com/?from=100&to=1000

Comment: i made it by putting an invisible input and getting the value of slider in it and than using $_GET

Answer (score 1):

### Use PDO build-In object. mysql_ functions were deprecated.

#### Initialize connection.

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_database";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $login, $password);
```

#### Use prepare statement.

```
$sh = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM price WHERE phone_price BETWEEN :from AND :to");
```

#### Bind values and value types.

```
$sh->bindParam(':from',$from,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sh->bindParam(':to',$to,PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

#### Fetch results into assoc array.

```
$res = $sh->fetch_all(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

#### Good Luck